# Download text file attachment from sender and move message to subfolder

Tags: vba, outlook

Every day we receive an email with several text file attachments. I want to download the attachments to a folder on the server, and then move the email to a subfolder in Outlook.

I found a script for downloading and saving the attachment and attached it to a rule. It works but I can't use the rules to then move the email to a subfolder as it automatically inserts the move before the download.

The alternative is to make the script more complex by combining the download and the move into one script.

I found several sample codes for moving messages but I need the rule to move only messages that have txt file attachments and from a specific email address and I don't have the capability to adapt that.

```vb
Public Sub SaveAutoAttach(item As Outlook.MailItem)
 
Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String

saveFolder = "P:\Shared Works\Catch Reports"
 
For Each object_attachment In item.Attachments
    If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".txt") Then
        object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & object_attachment.DisplayName
    End If
Next
 
End Sub
```

Code I found searches through an entire folder for matching criteria and then moves the message. I need the existing code to move the item that has been identified in the existing script.

Answer (score 0):

After your code saves your attachment and exits the `For Each/Next` loop, first define your move-to folder (I have assumed that your folder is called MyFolder and is a subfolder within your default inbox)...

```
Dim saveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Set saveToFolder = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("MyFolder") 'change the name of your destination folder accordingly
```

Then you can simply save your email item as follows...

```
item.Move saveToFolder
```

Comment: Your reply is much appreciated but unfortunately I still can't get it to work.  It may be that I'm placing the code in the wrong place, or because MAPI doesn't appear to be supported by my Outlook.  I tried changing the definition as below but that didn't make any difference as no doubt it is wrong!                                                                                                                   Dim saveToFolder As Outlook.Folder
Set saveToFolder = olns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Catch Reports")

Comment: In my example, I used a subfolder within my inbox as the move-to folder.  Is this the case with you?  Is your move-to folder actually a subfolder within your inbox?

Comment: Yes, it is.  It was a subfolder of a subfolder but I moved it out of that

Comment: Are you getting an error?  If so, which one and on which line?

Comment: No error message.  If I place the code after the loop, the items download but the emails remain in the Inbox.  If I place the code within the loop nothing happens at all.  The code runs without error but nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

OMG, it works!!  I had the definitions set in the wrong part of the code.  Final result is:

```
Public Sub SaveAutoAttach(item As Outlook.MailItem)
 
Dim object_attachment As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
Dim DestFolder As Outlook.Folder

' Folder location when I want to save my file
saveFolder = "P:\Shared Works\Catch Reports"
 
    For Each object_attachment In item.Attachments
    
    Dim saveToFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
    Set saveToFolder = Outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("Catch Reports") 'change the name of your destination folder accordingly

    If InStr(object_attachment.DisplayName, ".txt") Then
 
        object_attachment.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\" & object_attachment.DisplayName
 
    End If
    Next
    
    item.Move saveToFolder
  
End Sub
```

Thank you very much Domenic!!!